# como montar un web service java en ubuntu server

Tags: java, webservice, ubuntu

Buenos días el motivo de mi pregunta es como subir un servcio web que realice en  java a un servidor **ubuntu server  16.04** al momento de buscar información encontre como se realiza en php, no tengo muchos conocimientos sobre el tema ya tengo instalado el  **apache tomcat** pero no tengo idea como subir el web services si alguien me puede indicar como se puede realizar el procedimiento o en donde puedo encontrar información gracias de su atención

Comment: Una consulta el web services lo vas hacer el php o con JAX-RS

Comment: @RaulEstuardoCacachoAnton la voy hacer por JAX-RS

Comment: que versión de tomcat estas usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya teniendo tu war de tu aplicacion web java entonces solo deberias de subir el war a tomcat.

Tenes que crear una carpeta en 
apache-tomcat-7.0.22/webapps/ 
aqui la creas y pegas el archivo war, si te das cuenta un war es un comprimdo solo debes de descomprimirlo es esa carpeta.

Por último debemos arrancar Tomcat ejecutando el siguiente archivo:

apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/startup.sh

Entonces podremos acceder a nuestra aplicación web desde el navegador, lo más común sería:
http://localhost:8080/nombre de tu carpeta

Aca te dejo un link de como hacerlo

[tomcat](http://blog.cristianmartin.org/2012/03/ejecutar-un-proyecto-java-web-war-en-tomcat.html)